# ssl certificate on apache

Tags: raspbian, apache-httpd

I am following this tutorial to setup ssl on a raspbian.
http://www.flatmtn.com/article/setting-ssl-certificates-apache
The guide is for red hat.

Where is the default location to copy the key and certificate on the raspbian installation ?

4) Copy to the correct location

For apache 2.x on Red Hat using the default location, the directory is:

For the name-key.pem: cp name-key.pem /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/

For the certificate: cp name-cert.pem /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter where you put the files, Just make sure that Apache can read the files. You need to specify their location in the configuration file of Apache.

But just in case, the common location for the cert files in Debain is,

```
/etc/apache2/cert/
#or
/etc/ssl
-/etc/ssl/certs
-/etc/ssl/private
```